# Window form does not close

Tags: c#, windows

Hey guys i am new to the Windows application.

I have a form on which Login button click event i have shown to other Forms. Example like i have a login page after user authentication other two Forms shown. But i want after authentication of user Login Form should be close, But others two remain open.

Following is code, my Login Form name is `LogIn.cs`

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ValidateUser())
    {
       //Form1

        DetailForm form = new DetailForm(txtUserName.Text.ToString());
        form.Show();

        //Form2

        Progressbar progress = new Progressbar();
        progress.Show();
    }
}
```

please write some code

Comment: BTW: Progressbar is not a form OR I don't fully understand your code - sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can close the form using [Form.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)

Comment: Then you have closed your main form which leads to closing all forms created as childs.

Comment: thats because you are closing your main application form, this causes the application to exit ... you should change the way you are opening the login form in the program.cs

Comment: you are right my application exit...but how it will be resolve?

Comment: I assume the DetailForm asks for a password? you could use the OnLeave event of the input control to do the following:  
`/*close the dialog if the password seems valid
also, give the form a public variable that the parent form can read */

if (true == MyValidateFunction(txtPassword.Text)) {

  this.storedPassword = txtPassword.Text; 
  this.Close();

}`

edit: bah - I can't add newlines in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ValidateUser())
    {
       //Form1

        DetailForm form = new DetailForm(txtUserName.Text.ToString());
        form.Show();

        //Form2

        Progressbar progress = new Progressbar();
        progress.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this.Close() will close the parent form instead of the DetailForm. 
if you use form.close() instead of this.Close() in the above example, the DetailForm will close.

Comment: OK, good advice. I was pointing out that you must call the `Close()` method after showing other forms because if you close the only active form first then the application will close automatically. If you still want the form to be recalled later then use `Form.Hide()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Close" method on every form you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Main message loop of your application is in the LogIn form, it means that if you stop this message loop, your application stops.
Personally I won't let the LogIn form own the main message loop of your app. I wouldn't open the DetailForm and the ProgressBar from the LogIn form, it doesn't make much sense. I'd make some parent class which controls all of them.
If you do want the LogIn form to be the main of your app but hide it once the user logs in, you could either use Hide(), or run the two child windows in seperate Threads or Processes (not Highly recommended).

Comment: Found The Solution...I have just call Hide() methoed befor invoking other pages:) no need of seperate Threads e.t.c...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah was about to say tat and just noticed ur last comment!  the form which is having the ValidateUser is ur LoginForm.. ur question is not very clear. So it cant be closed. you should hide it if you dont want it in the background.